# How to reproject data from [-180 180] to [0 360]?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, leaflet, antimeridian

I have both a GeoJSON and shapefile of volcanoes along the Pacific Ring of Fire. The area I want to render in the map is right around the antimeridian, so Leaflet cuts it in half. I initially tried to use [VectorGrid.Slicer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) to wrap the data, but this was messing with the styling so I thought I would try and reproject the data itself in QGIS.

What is the best way to go about this? Duplicate the data and add 360 to each of the longitude values, or is there a more elegant solution?

I don't believe this is a repost, since most of the questions I've seen are asking how to reproject [0 360] to [-180 180].

Comment: This isn't a projection task so much as a transformation one. You can test to see if the feature is wholly or partially inside the range to which you want X values translated, and then either transform or clip and transform.  Dissolving features that span hemispheres would be a bonus feature.

Comment: How do I do that?